# C++17 "any_cast" fail for implicit ctor, throws exception

Tags: c++, c++17, throw, any

I've having `My` with an implicit ctor `My(int i)`, I wish to cast an int into My, so I have:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct My {
    My(int i) { cout << "int ctor\n"; }
};
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const My& m) {
    os << "My object\n";
    return os;
}
int main() {
    any a = 1;
    auto am = My(any_cast<int>(a));
    cout << a.type().name() << ": " << any_cast<int>(a) << '\n';
    cout << a.type().name() << ": " << any_cast<My>(a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Upon running, it prints:

```
int ctor
i: 1
i: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_any_cast'
  what():  bad any_cast
```

I expected that `any_cast<My>(a)` should be able to call `My(a)` to construct a new object, but actually not.

Did I mis-undertand anything?

Answer (score 2):

This is simply not how `std::any_cast` works. It is not literally a cast between types like e.g. `static_cast` is.

You *must* provide the exact type stored in the `std::any` object to access its value (via `std::any_cast`). It is impossible to imply any conversions.

Because the type stored in the `std::any` is only determined at runtime, the compiler would need to emit code for every possible type that could be stored in it and be convertible to the target type, if implicit conversions were allowed. That is clearly infeasible or impossible.

There are only very few situations where `std::any` is the right tool for the job. In particular it will not allow you to circumvent the statically-typed nature of C++.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected that any_cast(a) should be able to call My(a) to construct a new object, but actually not.

No, `any_cast<T>(a)` succeeds if and only if `T` is present in `a`. It answers the query whether there is `T` in `a`. Not whether there is some type implicitly convertible to `T`. You have to do that after extracting the value yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As for the [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast)

> Throws `std::bad_any_cast` if the typeid of the requested `T` does not match that of the contents of operand.

`a` should contain the exact type `My`.

> I expected that any_cast(a) should be able to call My(a) to construct a new object, but actually not.

It does not call converting constructors.